# Conversion of JSON to XML

Tags: java, javascript, xml, json, dynatree

I am converting JSON Values to XML. Instead of getting JSON properties as elements of XML I am getting `&quot;title&quot;:&quot;source&quot;`. The output I wanted is `<title>source</title>`. What is the mistake I am doing? I am writing this code in JavaScript function.

I am using x2js plugin for conversion and I have included it using script tag.

My code to convert dynatree to JSON and JSON to XML is:

```
var x2js = new X2JS();

var tree = $("#source").dynatree("getTree").toDict();
alert("  tree:"+tree);
var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(tree);//dynatree to JSON
alert(" jsonObject :"+jsonObject);       
var xmlAsStr = x2js.json2xml_str( jsonObject );//JSON to XML
alert("xml "+xmlAsStr);
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?!

Comment: Ya i know that ..first of all do you have an answer for this question? i need to use this data in java file..solution in either java or javascript both works for me. conversion in client side or server side i am not concerned with that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to not use `JSON.stringify(tree);` this escapes the string.

Set `var xmlAsStr = x2js.json2xml_str(tree);`